# infinite scroll with if/else statement

Tags: wordpress, pagination, infinite-scroll

With infinite scroll I am trying to load 3 posts at a time, but only posts that have a specific field (video) filled out.

So for example, my latest 2 posts have the field (video) filled out, the 3d post has not, the 4th post has. 
I want post 1, 2 & 4 loaded cause that makes 3. Then infinite scroll should load the next 3 posts that include video, etc.

Infinite scroll works, the pagination query works, BUT: because post 3 doesn't have the video field filled out, infinite scroll only loads posts 1 & 2 and doesn't add post 4 to complete the 3 posts I want to have at a time...

My code:

```
<div id="interviews">

<?php   $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query= null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query('paged='.$paged.'&cat=5&showposts=3');
        while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
        echo ('<ul id="infinite">');

    if (get('video_video', 1, TRUE)) {

        echo ('<li class="video">');
        $home = array("h" => 290, "w" => 380, "zc" => 1, "q" =>100);
        //echo get('video_video');
        echo ('With: ');
        echo get('participant_first_name');
        echo ('&nbsp;');
        echo get('participant_last_name');
        echo ('</li>');

        }else{ $video_video=false;
        echo ('');

         }  ?>

        <?php endwhile;?>
       </ul> 

<?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
<nav id="nav-below">
    <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; More', 'intowntheme' ) ); ?></div>
</nav>

<?php endif; ?>


</div><!--End interviews-->
```

Jquery script:

```
 jQuery('#interviews').infinitescroll({ 
navSelector  : "#nav-below",  // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
nextSelector : "#nav-below .nav-previous a",   // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
itemSelector : "li.video",  // selector for all items you'll retrieve
extraScrollPx: 50,    
loading         : {
     msgText: "<em>Loading the next year of Grantees...</em>",
    finishedMsg: "<em>You've reached the end of the Grantees.</em>"
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="interviews">
<?php echo ('<ul id="infinite">'); ?>
<?php 
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('paged='.$paged.'&cat=5&showposts=3&meta_key=video_video&orderby=meta_value&order=ASC'  . $post->ID);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_video', true) ) : ?>
    <li class="video"><?php $home = array("h" => 290, "w" => 380, "zc" => 1, "q" =>100);
            //echo get('video_video');
            echo ('With: ');
            echo get('participant_first_name');
            echo ('&nbsp;');
            echo get('participant_last_name');
            echo ('</li>');?>

<?php endif;?>


<?php endwhile;?>

<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video_video', true) ) { ?>
    <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
        <nav id="nav-below" >
        <div id="next"><?php next_posts_link( __( 'Scroll down for more', 'intowntheme' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; //end nav ?>
<?php } else {  ?>
<p>There are no interviews at the moment </p>
<?php }   ?>     
</ul>     
</div><!--End interviews-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that `get` function before.  Do you know which table it pulls its data from?  If it's `wp_postmeta`, you might be able to use [custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in your `WP_Query` to only retrieve the records you're interested in from the database.

Something like:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('paged='.$paged.'&cat=5&showposts=3&meta_key=video_video&meta_value=1');
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Hi there Hobo, 
You are right! I figured that out a few hrs ago and that works. I ended up with the above answer...